# Determinant properties with row reduction

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have the following question here.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $3 × 3$ matrices with $det(A) = 3$ and $det(B) = 2$. Let $C = \frac{1}{2}A^{-1}B^3$ and let $D$ be the reduced row echelon form of $C$. Then:
>
> $(a)$ $det(C)=\frac{4}{3}$, $det(D)=1$
>
> $(b)$ $det(C)=\frac{1}{3}$, $det(D)=1$
>
> $(c)$ $det(C)=\frac{4}{3}$, $det(D)=\frac{4}{3}$
>
> $(d)$ $det(C)=\frac{1}{3}$, $det(D)=3$
>
> $(e)$ $det(C)=\frac{1}{3}$, $det(D)=\frac{1}{3}$

The answer is supposed to be $b$. I know $det(C)=\frac{1}{3}$ just because of determinant properties. That was easy. I'm not 100% sure how the $RREF$ of $D$ comes into play here. I know that elementary row operations affect the determinant but HOW does that affects the determinant here.

Can someone provide any guidance as to how I would calculate $det(D)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the matrix $C$ is non-singular, its row reduced echelon form is just $I$.

Comment: Ohh. I overthought that way to much. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\det(C)=\det(\frac12A^{-1}B^3)=\frac1{2^3}\det(A^{-1}B^3)=\frac18\cdot\frac1{|A|}\cdot|B|^3=1/3$

$C$ is invertible. The [row-reduced echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) of $C$ is the identity matrix. So $D=I_3,\det(D)=1$.